# In MeteorJS, are files in node_modules cached?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, meteorite

When using a `npm` package with Meteor v0.6.6.3, making edits to the `npm` package's code found at `node_modules/npmPackage/something.js` does not seem to have any effect!

Are the npm packages somehow cached? If so, how can we clear it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Geoff Schmidt` from meteor core team wrote one day:

> Packages will automatically rebuild themselves when any of their
>   source files change (tracked by SHA1.) However, **if you are hacking on
>   the package system itself**, you might have a reason to want to force a
>   rebuild of all packages.
>
> You can do this with the undocumented command
>   **'meteor rebuild-all'**.

[Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/WaLmeo3uth4)

Comment: I tried this with Meteor 1.2.0.2 and I get an error: 'rebuild-all' is not a Meteor command.

Comment: So it looks like that command is deprecated. Please note answer was given 22.11.2013 - a lot of changes happened in meteor since then.